# メタでも「スタック・オーバーフロー初心者」と出てしまう

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

メインサイトで充分信用度を稼いでらっしゃる方でも、メタサイトに来たのが初めてだと「スタック・オーバーフロー初心者」と表示されることに気付きました。本来は「スタック・オーバーフロー メタ初心者」と表示されるべきです。

英語だとどちらも "New contributor" となっており翻訳用 string も同一なので起こった現象のようです。このままだと Transifex / Traducir では対応できないのですが、どうすれば良いでしょうか。

- 「スタック・オーバーフロー初心者」という訳そのものを変える？
- メインサイトとメタサイトでstringを分けてもらう？
- メタサイトではそもそも「スタック・オーバーフロー初心者」が出ないようにしてもらう？（英語版では「メインサイトで活躍していてもメタを知っているとは限らない」として[却下されていました](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372906/5989200)）

[image: メタで「スタック・オーバーフロー初心者」と出ているスクリーンショットです]

Comment: 「新しい参加者」みたいな感じに訳を変えればどうにか出来る気はしますが、現状の訳を維持するならメインとメタで分けるのが一番わかりやすくなりそうだと思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@supa さんもおっしゃっていますが、 "New Contributor" を「新しい参加者」という翻訳に変更する、のがいいと思います。

仮に自分たちが stackexchange の開発者であったとして、そこをあえて別実装するような機能要求は、よほどの合理的理由がない限り、却下したくなるだろうな、と思うのがその理由です。

---

(追記@2020/01/10)
翻訳が「スタック・オーバーフロー初心者」から「新しい参加者」に変更されました。

[image: Yaakovさんのプロファイルを使用させていただきました]

Comment: [新しい参加者](https://ja.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=(%3Fi)new%20contributor)という翻訳にTraducirで変更され、次のビルドで適用される予定です。